# How to download data into R if the proxy redirect to the login page

Tags: r, redirect, proxy, web-scraping

There is a large [database of OECD](http://stats.oecd.org/) which is however accessible only to subscribers. My university is subscribed but the problem is that the access is via the library page. When you click the link, you are redirected to a login page and then you can use the data, but through library proxy: at the end of the link the address of the library is added. Like that:

*stats.oecd.org.ezproxy.myuni.edu*

The OECD allows to download the data in SDMX (XLS) format which is easily done with XML2R package. But the problem is that I can't use the link above because there is no way to add credentials.

How it can be bypassed?

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: It would be great if the answerer suggests how to deal with password login as well.

Comment: What have you tried? The httr package makes these sorts of things fairly easy most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [RJSDMX](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJSDMX/index.html) package. The data you are looking for are probably in the **OECD_RESTR** provider. The proxy will not be a problem, as the package functions query the SDMX web services directly and, since the provider is a restricted one, you'll be prompted for authentication when you query it.

You can find more information about the package and its configuration in the project [wiki](https://github.com/amattioc/SDMX/wiki)